# pushing viewcontroller using ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have two scenario for the project with ARC and project without ARC.

1) The project without ARC.we can use the following.

```
 MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
 [viewController release];
```

2)How can I achieve the above in the project which is with ARC.

```
      a)where can I allocate memory?
      b)where can I release viewcontroller after pushing?
      c)is there any standard for it?
```

Comment: What have you tried and errors did it produce? Actually, it is obvious you haven't tried it yet. If you are using ARC that code won't even compile because you cannot release when you are using ARC.

Comment: ya. i want to know the right code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ARC you do not need to release the viewController, the compiler will add the `release` and `retain` for you..

So in ARC this will do:

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Using `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` will result in a compiler error.

---

Be aware that you will need to use the `@property` correctly when using ARC. Use `strong` for properties that you want to retain and `weak` for properties that you just want to `assign`. If you want iOS 4.3 support you can't use `weak` but should use `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: to which variable, can I set strong property in you sample code.you have allocated memory for  MyViewController locally.will it be deallocated by ARC automatically whenever it is not needed.

Comment: You don't need it in your code it was ment as something you will need take in consideration when using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

In ARC you don't user `release`, `autorelease` or `retain`. ARC does that for you. You simply allocate it as usual with `[[Class alloc] init];` but you don't need to send the above messages to your object.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Thats it only if you are using ARC, no need to release the viewcontroller after pushing, as ARC takes care of all releases and it inserts itself all the releases at compile time only, so it will work fine.

Comment: I have one issue with this.When I did this and checked with profiler memory is increasing very fast.Seems ARC not release the object immediately.Do u have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The pushing of the view controller with the ARC enabled is very simple:

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

This is because ARC automatically counts the active pointers to the allocated objects, and when the there are no active pointer to the object, the object is automatically released for you. So you don't have to call those methods yourself.